# PHP trim entire words

Tags: php, string, trim

How to trim entire words from php string

like I dont want `"foo"`, `"bar"`, `"mouse"` words on left and `"killed"` on the end of string.

So `"fo awesome illed"` would `not` be trimmed

But `"foo awesome killed"` => `" awesome "`

`"killed awesome foo"` not trimmed (killed trimmed from right, rest from left)

When I'm using `ltrim($str, "foo")`; it will trim any letter from `"foo"` - `"f"` or `"o"`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `preg_replace()` to replace the strings with an empty string.

```
$str = preg_replace('/^(foo|bar|mouse)|killed$/', '', $str);
```

Go to [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) to learn more about regexp.

Comment: umm, really no build in function? Imo its common 'need'

Comment: Doesn't seem very common to me. What's the application that needs this?

Comment: `trim` is usually used for removing things like whitespace or delimiters, that's why it takes a set of characters, not an exact string.

Comment: `ltrim($str, "abc")` is equivalent to `preg_replace('/^[abc]*/, '', $str)`. `rtrim($str, "def")` is equivalent to `preg_replace('/[def]*$/', '', $str)`. `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string, `[...]` match any of the enclosed characters, and `*` matches any number of the preceding regexp.

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace($replaceme, $withme, $here)` works much faster (and is easier) if you dont need advanced regex features.
If you know the exact word you are looking for ($replaceme) and you want to delete it you can just use "" (empty string) in the $withme parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Use preg_match function and create your own patteren based on your requirment.

```
<?php
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^foo$killed/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: No this example does not work on many levels. You cannot have $ in the middle of a regex and expect a match, for one. Also, you return an array, not a string.